# Javascript calculation not working.

Tags: javascript

I have one page and two separate script to calculate value but if I repeat two time Javascript in one page it is not working how can I do this?
Please help in this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function updatesum() {
    var total = (document.form.daysone.value -0)*(document.form.daystwo.value -0)* (document.form.amount.value -0)/ (document.form.year.value -0)/ (document.form.month.value -0);
    document.form.total.value = total.toFixed(3);
}
//--></script>
 <form name="form" action="enter.php" method="post" id="searchform">
     <p>
       <label class="field">15 Days</label>
       <input  name="daysone" type="text" value="15"  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p> 
          <p>
       <label class="field">686 Days</label>
       <input  name="daystwo" type="text" value="686"  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p> 
              <p>
       <label class="field">Amount </label>
       <input  name="amount" type="text" value=""  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p>
              <p>
       <label class="field">year </label>
       <input  name="year" type="text" value="365"  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p>
              <p>
       <label class="field">month </label>
       <input  name="month" type="text" value="30"  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p>
      <p>
        <label class="field" >Total </label>
        <input name="total" type="text" value="" />
     </p>





      <strong>next one</strong>


<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function updatesum() {
    var total1 = (document.form1.days1.value -0)*(document.form1.days1.value -0)* (document.form1.amount1.value -0)/ ;
    document.form1.total1.value = total1.toFixed(3);
}
//--></script>
 <form name="form1" action="enter.php" method="post" id="searchform">
     <p>
       <label class="field">15 Days</label>
       <input  name="days1" type="text" value="15"  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p> 
          <p>
       <label class="field">686 Days</label>
       <input  name="days2" type="text" value="686"  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p> 
              <p>
       <label class="field">Amount </label>
       <input  name="amount1" type="text" value=""  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p>

      <p>
        <label class="field" >Total </label>
        <input name="total1" type="text" value="" />
     </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function, and replace your with this one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatesum() {


    var total = (document.form.daysone.value -0)*(document.form.daystwo.value -0)* (document.form.amount.value -0)/ (document.form.year.value -0)/ (document.form.month.value -0);
    document.form.total.value = total.toFixed(3);
}
</script>
 <form name="form" action="enter.php" method="post" id="searchform">
     <p>
       <label class="field">15 Days</label>
       <input  name="daysone" type="text" value="15"  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p>
          <p>
       <label class="field">686 Days</label>
       <input  name="daystwo" type="text" value="686"  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p>
              <p>
       <label class="field">Amount </label>
       <input  name="amount" type="text" value=""  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p>
              <p>
       <label class="field">year </label>
       <input  name="year" type="text" value="365"  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p>
              <p>
       <label class="field">month </label>
       <input  name="month" type="text" value="30"  onChange="updatesum()" />
     </p>
      <p>
        <label class="field" >Total </label>
        <input name="total" type="text" value="" />
     </p>
```

Comment: ok suppose if i repeat 3 time or 4 time so what can i change?in script

Comment: your code is working but there is error in your function try above.

Comment: its working please enable javascript on your browser

Comment: dear it is seprate working only i want repeat javascript two time in my page and i have two form see my question

Answer (score 0):

I think the same name is creating a problem here, Is it necessary to have the same name for both the functions?

Please try to change the name from UpdateSum in second one to something else.

Comment: i already try all this thing but i dont understand what is the problem and why it is not working

Comment: not working i change all thing but its not working i dont understand what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the duplicate function name.

Since, both the functions have a different calculation, it is better you name them differently and update your html accordingly.

There is another way in which you can do this, but you'll have to pass a parameter to the function which will differentiate between the two forms.

```
function updatesum(formName) {
    var total, total1;
    if (formName == 'form') {
        total = (document.form.daysone.value - 0) * (document.form.daystwo.value - 0) * (document.form.amount.value - 0) / (document.form.year.value - 0) / (document.form.month.value - 0);
        document.form.total.value = total.toFixed(3);
    } else if (formName == 'form1') {
        total1 = (document.form1.days1.value - 0) * (document.form1.days1.value - 0) * (document.form1.amount1.value - 0);
        document.form1.total1.value = total1.toFixed(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: i change function name also but it is notworking and i also try ur code both are not working